# I can't change the annotation color of my google chart

Tags: javascript, charts, colors, annotations, google-visualization

I'm trying for hours to change the color of the rectangle which is next to my column chart (i'm new using google chart) and i can't find a solution can you help me pls ?

This is my code :

```
 var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                
                ['Element', 'Nombre de projets en cours',{ role: 'style' }, { role: 'annotation' }, ],
                ['Abel', abelProjet, '#05204A', '' ],
                ['Evan', evanProjet, '#05204A', '' ],
                ['Florent', florentProjet, '#05204A', '' ],
                ['Florian', florianProjet, '#05204A', '' ],
                ['Martin', martinProjet, '#05204A', '' ],
                ['Novan', novanProjet, '#05204A', '' ],
                ['Valentin', valentinProjet, '#05204A', '' ]
            ]);

            var options3 = {};
```

And this is how it's looking :
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwLTc.jpg)

The rectangle is supposed to be in the same color of the columns right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `colors` chart option...

this is what drives the legend.

```
var options3 = {
  colors: ['#05204A']
};
```

this option will color the bars the same, and the style role can be removed.
the style role is only needed if you need to override the color of a specific bar in a series.